# Bind ItemsSource to Column of ComboBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, listbox, datatemplate

As per title. The column is in a DataTemplate.
This is what I have currently:

```
var test = FindChildControl<ComboBox>(this, "PrintCode") as ComboBox;
        test.ItemsSource = listPrintCode;
        MessageBox.Show(test.Items.Count.ToString());
```

FindChildControl method:

```
private DependencyObject FindChildControl<T>(DependencyObject control, string ctrlName)
    {
        int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
        for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
            var fe = child as FrameworkElement;
            // Not a framework element or is null
            if (fe == null) return null;

            if (child is T && fe.Name == ctrlName)
            {
                // Found the control so return
                return child;
            }
            DependencyObject nextLevel = FindChildControl<T>(child, ctrlName);
            if (nextLevel != null)
                return nextLevel;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

XAML - Template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="lbCommsItemSetTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0" Width="Auto">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name:" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Blue" Margin="40,0,0,0"
            Text="{Binding CommonDesc}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Serial:" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Blue" Margin="35,0,0,0"
            Text="{Binding Serial}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="lbIssueTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="0" Width="Auto">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name:" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Blue" Margin="50,0,0,0"
            Text="{Binding CommonDesc}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Qty:" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Blue" Margin="35,0,0,0"
                     Text="{Binding LoanQty}" PreviewTextInput="UIElement_OnPreviewTextInput" MaxLength="4"
                     GotKeyboardFocus="UIElement_OnGotKeyboardFocus" MaxLines="1"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="PrintCode" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      SelectedValuePath="PrintCode" DisplayMemberPath="PrintCode"/>
            <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" IsChecked="{Binding PrintShortSerial}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

XAML - ListBox that implements the Template

```
<telerik:RadListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0, 5, 5, 5"
            x:Name="listBoxIssue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Height="690" Width="793"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lbIssueTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            SelectionMode="Multiple" Drop="ListBoxIssue_OnDrop"/>
```

The message box is just simply to confirm that 'listPrintCode' and 'FindChildControl' is working as intended. But the ComboBox didn't display anything, even if it's just 1 ComboBox. If I apply the codes to a normal ComboBox not part of the template, it's all fine. I think there's an obvious flaw in my code, which is that there's nothing that seems to apply to all ComboBoxes in the column. So my question is, how do I bind my ItemsSource as the column of the comboboxes?

Note: The number of rows (ComboBoxes) are not fixed.

Comment: you may not require all this effort to bind to a collection, perhaps try to simplify your question, you may perhaps get better answers.

Comment: where is your PrintCode property to which you are binding in xaml i.e which class contains Printcode property ?

Comment: @nit PrintCode will come from listPrintCode, which is a list of PrintOptions objects. PrintOptions contains the property PrintCode. I intend this to be binded to the ComboBox to give choices. Another object, which is binded to the RadListBox also contains the PrintCode property, which is chosen to be the SelectedValue of the ComboBox.